# Which of these two numpy slices are better to use?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I am learning Python through an online course. We were asked to slice a 6x6 numpy array and get the diagonal. As a group we developed two methods, shown below. Is one better than the other?

```
import numpy as n
six = n.arange(1, 73, 2)
six.reshape(6,6)
```

Solutions found

```
six[::7]
six.reshape(36)[::7]
```

My answers both return `array([ 1, 15, 29, 43, 57, 71])`

I like the first, my partner likes the second. Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Check the shape of `six`.  I don't think it ever is 6x6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
six.reshape(6,6)
```

does not modify `six` itself: it just returns a new 2D array but leaves `six` unchanged. So, your two methods are in effect one and the same method.

You can verify this by doing:

```
>>> six = np.arange(1, 73, 2)
>>> six.reshape(6,6)
>>> print(six)
```

You will get a 1D array like:

```
[ 1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39
 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71]
```

Therefore, I declare that the answer that does not use the **unnecessary** `reshape` call (assuming `six` is a flat array created with `np.arange(1, 73, 2)`) is **the best answer** :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's fix your code a bit first so it does what you intend:

```
six = np.arange(1, 73, 2).reshape(6, 6)
```

Now comparing your approach:

```
>>> six[::7]
array([[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11]])
```

To your partner's:

```
>>> six.reshape(36)[::7]
array([ 1, 15, 29, 43, 57, 71])
```